# Insertion Sort Algoritm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a program to order a list of numbers using insertion sorting and there's something I'm not understanding.

```
function insertionSort(array) {
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        let j = i - 1

        while (j > 0 && array[j] < array[j - 1]) {
            [array[j - 1], array[j]] = [array[j], array[j - 1]]
            j--
        }
    }
    return array
}

insertionSort([25,250,-2,62,12,0,-1,6,2500, 35])
```

At first iteration `j=0` so the while loop is not running.

At second iteration `j=1` and because the `250<25` the while loop again is running.

At third iteration `j=2` and the loop is running.

My question is when we do `j--` in a while loop, does  `j` out of while loop keeps the value of `j--` or it is changes?

Comment: in order to compare values in a descending order

Comment: Why would the value of `j` change after the loop? Variables only change when you assign to them.

Comment: But you don't use `j` after the loop, so why does it matter if it keeps its value or not? The next iteration of the outer loop resets `j = i - 1`.

Comment: Barmar so it takes the values of i ,and does not changes after the while loop. am i right?

Comment: Yes, because that's what `let j = i - 1;` sets it to.

Comment: Why we need to do j-- in a loop?

Comment: If you don't do that, `[array[j - 1], array[j]] = [array[j], array[j - 1]]` will keep swapping the same two elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250607/discussion-between-diana-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

When you execute j— within a while loop, the value of j is decremented by one, but only for that iteration of the while loop. Outside of the while loop (that is, after the loop has completed), the value of j will remain the same as before the loop began.

When j is decremented inside the while loop in your insertion sort function, it only affects the value of j for that iteration of the loop. When the loop is finished and control returns to the outer for loop, the value of j is reset to its initial value (i-1).

In your example, when j is decremented from 2 to 1 inside the while loop during the third iteration, the value of j outside the loop is unaffected. When the while loop is finished, the value of j remains 2 for the third iteration of the for loop.